# In what order are local scoped objects destructed?

Tags: c++, scope, destructor

Will `foo` be destructed before `bar`, after `bar`, or is there no guarantee either way?

```
myFunction()
{
    Foo foo = Foo();
    Bar bar = Bar();
    return;
}
```

Comment: No objects are created in your example. Instead, two functions are declared, named `foo` and `bar`. See ["most vexing parse"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Darn you and your correctness. ;) I've updated the question to reflect the intent.

Comment: Order of Destruction: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8183zf3x.aspx

Comment: Just for the record, C++ doesn't have function scoped objects.  What you call function scope is just a special case of local scope.

Comment: @JamesKanze Thanks for the information. I've updated the question to be more accurate.

Answer (score 7):

They are destroyed in the reverse order of their declaration. In

```
{
 Foo foo = Foo();
 Bar bar = Bar();
}
```

`foo` constructed first, then `bar`. When going out of scope - `bar` destructed first, then `foo`.

Answer (score 1):

The memory of a function is called "the stack". And like every other stack, the last thing you put on, is the first thing you'll take off.

So, effectively, when the function returns and the local memory goes out of scope, all local variables are destructed in **reverse order**.

That is always the case, and you most definitely can rely on that (within the same thread).

Comment: This is very misleading, because temporary objects are also placed on the stack, and they will be destructed before any non-temporaries (at the end of the full expression.

Comment: No, they will follow the same order. Temporaries are usually put on later, and that's why they are being destroyed earlier.

Comment: @user2032040 James is right even in a deeper sense, I think. Compiler will put local variables on stack the way it sees fit, it is not restricted to follow the order you declare them in. The constructors and destructors will be called in the right order, but location on stack depends on what compiler decides to do.

Comment: @user2032040: Yes and no. When you write `S s = std::string("Hello");` the compiler need to create a temporary to hold the `std::string`. It translates the code to: `std::string __tmp("Hello"); S s = __tmp; DESTROY(__tmp);`. Note how the destruction of `__tmp` is called *before* that of `s` even though it was *also* built *before* ?

Comment: @MatthieuM. Yes.  This is almost always the case when temporaries are involved in the initialization of local variables.

Comment: Ok, you mean those temporaries. Those are anonymous, the programmer didn't write them, so the order only matters to the machine. The question here is what the order would be for the variables that the programmer did write. And in that case, you can rely on the reverse order.

Answer (score -3):

In inheritance it is reverse order. In your case, It is in same order of creation.

```
 Foo f= new Foo();
 Bar b= new Bar();
```

f is destroyed before b

Comment: That wouldn't even compile. C++ != Java.